# How to format/align conky's configuration file?

Tags: conky

My current conky config file looks like below and I find it pretty ugly.

> TEXT
>
> Temp: ${color e0e0e0}${acpitemp}${color} | Uptime: ${color
>   e0e0e0}${uptime_short}${color} | Cpu: ${color e0e0e0}${cpu}%${color} 
>   Ram: ${color e0e0e0}${mem}${color}  Swap: ${color
>   e0e0e0}${swapperc}%${color}  Disk: ${color e0e0e0}${fs_used_perc
>   /}%${color}

Now when I try changing it to the below format it disturbs my `conky's layout`.

> TEXT
>
> Temp: ${color e0e0e0}${acpitemp}${color} |
>
> Uptime: ${color e0e0e0}${uptime_short}${color} |
>
> Cpu: ${color e0e0e0}${cpu}%${color}  Ram: ${color
>   e0e0e0}${mem}${color}  Swap: ${color e0e0e0}${swapperc}%${color} 
>   Disk: ${color e0e0e0}${fs_used_perc /}%${color}

**Currently**

[image]

**After changing**

[image]

Now you can see as soon as I change my config file's format it changes my conky's layout.

So, my question is there any way through which I can keep my current conky layout but format/align my config file's `text` in a better way so that it is easy to understand and edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to align or arrange the text in your config file without influencing the conky itself, but maybe setting a Highlight Mode in the text editor you use can help to get better oversight of the text. I use 'Scientific matlab' in gedit, you get different colors for different kinds of items...

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. Currently I am using [`\ (backslash)`](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html#TEXT) to keep them on separate line and keeping my current layout intact

Comment: I didn't know that one, thanks for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

From [Configuration Settings - Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html):

> TEXT -- After this begins text to be formatted on screen. `Backslash (\)` escapes newlines in the text section. [...]

The following shows a fragment of the configuration file:

[image: conky config file in vi]

and the final result:

[image: conky output]

*LA* and *Uptime* are on different lines in `conky`'s configuration file, but they are on the same line on screen. Same for *Frequency*, *MHz*, and *GHz*.